# Branch off old commit after push?

Tags: git, merge, branching-and-merging

I have a remote master and a local master, off of which I branch for features. I then merge my local branches into local master, and push local master to remote for testing and deployment (I have to push to the remote to deploy to test and prod).

I have two features, A and B. I have pushed A to the remote and it is still in testing. I want to start work on B, and be able to deploy B regardless of the state of approval for A.

I have two questions:

1. Does that fact that my local master contains feature A prevent me from deploying *only* feature B, because I've already merged, or will a new branch from the previous commit allow me to effectively undo A, and push B (only)?
2. If the above is true, can I merge A into B if A gets approved before I finish B? (I still have the local feature A branch.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, Yes* - `git checkout -b branch_B origin/master` should let you start working on a new branch
2. Yes - `git merge origin/master` (assuming origin/master contains the approved 'A' branch, and your current branch is B)

* This does assume that you you can either (a) move your local master branch to the new 'B' branch, or (b) don't have to do the push to remote from your local environment.
For example: `git push origin B` instead of `git push origin master`

For reference, here is a git repository with a new B branch:

```
*---* - origin/master
    |\
    | * - A, master, origin/A
     \
      * - B
```

Comment: For #1 above, I'll need to reference the previous commit, correct? (Without doing so, I'll get feature A in my branch, no?)

Comment: You are correct.  I said 'origin/master' for the checkout, because I assumed that would still be the root commit.  If you want to reffer to it by it's hash value, do:
 `git checkout -b new_branch_b <hash>`
or `git checkout <hash>` (of root commit) then `git checkout -b new_branch_b`